# One-to-many bidirectional mapping and persistance order issue

Tags: java, jpa, orm, mapping

I've got two entities that have a bidirectional one-to-many relationship:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
public Collection<EmployeeMapping> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
    Department object = new Department();
    object.setName("Test Department Object");
    assertEquals("Object ID is not persistent yet", 0L, object.getId());
    EmployeeMapping employee1 = new EmployeeMapping();
    employee1.setName("Employee 1");
    EmployeeMapping employee2 = new EmployeeMapping();
    employee2.setName("Employee 2");
    Collection<EmployeeMapping> collection = ImmutableSet.of( employee1, employee2 );
    object.setEmployees( collection );
    departmentDao.save(object);
    assertNotEquals("Object ID is persistent", 0L, object.getId());

    Department actualObject = departmentDao.get( object.getId() );
    assertEquals("The actual object in the database must be equal to the original value", object, actualObject);
```

employee1 and employee2 are not saved. After test execution they are not present in the table. actualObject - of the Departme type - does present.

My question is why when I get a deparment using: `departmentDao.get( object.getId() );` the `actualObject` have a collection of employees, although they cannot be unnloaded from the table. They have not been saved. Maybe departmentDao uses a cache inside. I'm not sure, please explain it.

Anyway, I'd like so `object` and `actualObject` would be not be equal in this test. How can I archive it? I expect them to be equal only when I save both employees.

And the last question, the order of entities saving. Both employee and department have a link to each other. It's a bidirectional relationship. Should I save first a department and only then employees or the order does not matter? Could you please explain this for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I would like the actual object and the object to be different":
This depends on :

1. The implementation of the equals method
2. Wether or not the SET operation of the DAO updates the "object" by reference

Order of saving one2many:
The object that holds the foreign key should be saved LAST.
In this is example you have :

1. employee(employeeid, name, etc..., **departmentID**)
2. department(departmentID, departmentNAme, etc...)

==> this implies that the department should allready be saved (the department id must exists/be resolved) when saving the employee.

- The actualObject (retrieved from departmenDao) contains empty collection of employee's because the employees are not saved as you said so yourself.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: The last question. The actualObject contains not empty collecton. And I cannot undestand why.